# VB Retrieve file directory path from a process

Tags: vb.net

I've worked with VBA for a few years, but I'm switching to VB to utilize more powerful coding practices.

I have the following VB code to attach an Excel workbook to an open instance:

```
Dim FullFilePath as String = "C:\Temp"
Dim WrkBk = as Excel.Workbook
WrkBk = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(FullFilePath)
```

This seems to require the workbook's directory path.

I have the following code to cycle through Excel processes.

```
FileName = "ABCD.xlsm"

For Each P As Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
    With P
        If .MainWindowTitle.ToLower.Contains(FileName.ToLower) Then

            'don't know the code to get the directory where the p process is located

            WrkBk = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(FilePath)

            Exit For
        End If
    End With
Next
```

The path to ABCD.xlsm is not always the same for my application. Everything I've googled for getting a directory of the process returns the EXCEL.EXE path or returns the path of the vb project's working directory. I really need it to return something like: "C:\Temp\Tools\ABCD.xlsm" so I can attach WrkBk to the process.

Any Ideas? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: First you are saying you need the path to the excell workbook and then the running process? Did you try to just give the full path (including the filename) of your workbook?

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation....I have 2 workbooks that will be open in different instances of Excel. I need to pass information back and forth. Both files are already open when my code runs. One workbook's path will be static so the BindToMoniker function works. The other path will be dynamic and the BindToMoniker doesn't work. I'm trying to capture the full path of the dynamic book so I can take control of it. I've isolated the book through the process loop, but I'm unable to return the path........the gist of it is I'm trying to take control of book already open without knowing the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
For Each wb As Excel.Workbook In xl.Workbooks
  MsgBox(wb.FullName)
Next wb
xl = Nothing
```

Comment: SSS, I think I've narrowed down what I need to be done (which I didn't state in my initial post). I need something that will hook an Excel Application object to a workbook that is opened before my VB application runs. I need it find the workbook even when multiple instances of Excel are open (it could reside in the 1st instance, 3rd instance, or last instance). The workbook directory is also dynamic because the workbook can be opened from many different locations. I've tried using a "for each process" loop to find the file, but can't find how to hook the object or return the process file path.

Comment: I haven't got time to try it out, but maybe this article might help you? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238975

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it.

Windows API....

```
Private Delegate Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr, ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumWindowsProc, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Int32) As Int32
Private Const MAX_TITLE As Int32 = 256
Private Const S_OK As Int32 = &H0

Private Function GetClassName(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As String
    Dim name As New String(" "c, MAX_TITLE)
    Dim len = GetClassName(hwnd, name, MAX_TITLE)
    If len = 0 Then Return Nothing
    Return name.Remove(len)
End Function

Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "OLEACC.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal dwId As Int32, ByVal riid As Byte(), ByRef ppvObject As IntPtr) As Integer
Private Const OBJID_NATIVEOM As Int32 = &HFFFFFFF0
Private IID_IDispatch As New Guid("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}")
```

function...

```
Function EnumCWindows(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    Dim name = GetClassName(hwnd)
    If name = "EXCEL7" OrElse name = "EXCEL10" Then
        Dim ptr As IntPtr
        If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IID_IDispatch.ToByteArray(), ptr) = S_OK Then
            Dim win = CType(Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(ptr), Excel.Window)
            Dim sheet = CType(win.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
            Dim book = CType(sheet.Parent, Excel.Workbook)
            If book.FullName.ToLower.Contains("wpp tools") Then
                FoundTheFile = True
                WPPFilePath = book.FullName
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

then in your code....

```
For Each p In Process.GetProcesses
    If p.ProcessName = "EXCEL" Then
        EnumChildWindows(p.MainWindowHandle, AddressOf EnumCWindows, IntPtr.Zero)
        If FoundTheFile = True Then Exit For
    End If
Next
If FoundTheFile = False Then
    MsgBox("Targeted file was not found.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "File Find Error")
    End
End If
```

I hope this can help someone else as I've searched for a week now!